# What is the exception "cannot open log" invalid operation exception from Azure .net SDK?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

I am getting the following exception when sending batched messages to the Azure Service Bus Standard Tier. What is the exception that talks about opening log for source? I am using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus latest .net SDK.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open log for source 'Microsoft.ServiceBus'. You may not have write access.
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpSender.<SendBatchInternalAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpSender.<>c.<<SendBatchAsync>b__18_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.<>c__20`1.<<RunOperation>b__20_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.<RunOperation>d__21`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.<RunOperation>d__21`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.<RunOperation>d__20`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpSender.<SendBatchAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusSender.<SendMessagesAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
```

Comment: How are you connecting to your Service Bus Namespace?

Comment: I generate a SAS token and then use the URI.

Comment: That's a new one.   The stack trace appears to indicate that this is a service exception and not something in the client.   Would you mind opening an issue in the [Azure SDK for .NET  repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net) or an Azure [support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) so that we can request assistance from the Service Bus service team?

Comment: @JesseSquire Created issue - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/27067

Comment: @JesseSquire : If the exception happens during a batch send, I guess the whole batch is treated as a whole. If I send a batch of 50 messages, is there a possibility that 20 get delivered and 30 remain undelivered? My understanding is that it is either all or none. Right?

Comment: Your understanding is correct; there is no possibility of partial success.  A batch is considered a single atomic unit.  All messages in the batch will succeed or all will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Jesse Squire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159548/jesse-squire) and [Arun Prakash Nagendran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11028462/arun-prakash-nagendran) for your valuable discussions.

> As this is an on-going bug, bug details and the mitigation plans are
> being discussed @
> https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/27067
>
> More details are being tracked @
> https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/27067

Comment: Am I not eligible to get a bug bounty? ;)

Comment: there was no bounty set on this question to award you. stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: I was not referring to the StackOverflow bounty. Does Microsoft have reward programs on finding bugs with their services?

Comment: Checking with appropriate team. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Madhu, Were you able to check with the team?

Comment: @ArunPrakashNagendran, apologies for delayed response. You can submit your Bug bounty request @ https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc/bounty. It will under go an initial check, get approved and then you'll receive your bounty.